# How to get a call stack in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to get a call stack at a particular point in the code because in running Mocha tests I only get the line # that failed and not the calling context.  so I tried using the `console.trace()` but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ phantomjs
phantomjs> function x() { console.trace(); } x();

undefined
```

is this not how the function is supposed to work? clearly, PhantomJS implements it, but it seems not to work.